# Binary Tree Output

Tags: java, binary-tree

Hi how do I make the program output the sum of the numbers instead of giving them out seperately?

```
public class Tree {
private Node root;
public int sum;

public class Node{
    private Node left;
    private Node right;
    private int val;

    public Node(int data) {
        this.val = data;
    }
}

public void createTree() {
    Node first = new Node(7);
    Node second = new Node(2);
    Node third = new Node(6);
    Node fourth = new Node(4);


    root = first;
    first.left = second;
    first.right = third;

    second.left = fourth;

}

public void Sum(Node root) {
    if(root == null) {
        return;
    }
    System.out.print(root.val + " ");
    Sum(root.left);
    Sum(root.right);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Tree tree = new Tree();
    tree.createTree();
    tree.Sum(tree.root);
}
}
```

Current output is 7 2 6 4 but I want them to be added into a sum in the System outprint if possible. I couldnt get it to work for some reason so maybe someone can help me with it.

Comment: Hint: You have a method called `Sum` which is not doing any summing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can recursively get the sum by doing the following:

```
public double sum(Node root) {      
  double leftSum, rightSum, totalSum;

  if (root == null) {
   totalSum = 0;
   return totalSum;
  }else {
   leftSum = sum(root.left);
   rightSum = sum(root.right);
   totalSum = root.val + leftSum + rightSum;
   return totalSum;
  }
}
```

Comment: that function looks good as it is but can you help me adding it into the code?

Comment: it tells me it cannot convert double to int

Comment: Change the method signature to use double, not int, if you're summing double values or use int in the method signature and leftSum, rightSum and totalSum variables if you're returning a total int value. I've changed the answer to double just for convenience sake. Try it now.

Comment: It worked. Now the System print is missing still. Can't I just output totalSum now?

Comment: Yes you definitely can. System.out.println(tree.sum(tree.root)).

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the sum of the left and right nodes and print the return value from `main()`. Also, there's no need for `sum()` to be an intance method since you're passing in `root`:

```
public static int sum(Node root) {
    if(root == null) {
        return 0;
    }
    return sum(root.left) + sum(root.right);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Tree tree = new Tree();
    tree.createTree();
    System.out.println(sum(tree.root));
}
```